# Click() not working on a button but getText() works fine with same xpath in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, button, xpath, selenium-webdriver, click

I am trying to click a button on a pop up using xpath, I tried the following code:

```
MySuite.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[9]/div[3]/div/button[4]")).click();
```

It does not click on the intended button but when I use same xpath and use getText() method it returns me correct value:

```
String test=MySuite.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[9]/div[3]/div/button[4]")).getText();
System.out.println(test);
```

I have tried using Implicit wait also but not to no use. Please help what all reasons can be possible for button not getting clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be:

1. Button is not click-able at that moment where you are trying to click on it. So use an explicit expected condition to be ensure that button is click-able.

   `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpath")));`
2. Or, Try to click on parent of button element.If it is possible.
3. Or, Inject java script explicitly to click on required button.

   `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Comment: I applied Thread.sleep() and it worked but it didn't with implicit wait. don't know if this is the right way to implement or not.